# How to get data from DB Browser for SQLite and Display the data from Listview android

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, android-database

I have create the two tables in DB Browser fist category and second people.

category have two fields first id and second name and people have three fields id,namd and category id.

Hear I have put five items in category fields and many people name using category_id how to show data List view or Recyclerview

**I have static add data in DB Browser**

plz help me!!

**DataBaseHelper.java**

```
public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.example.mobisharnam.database/databases/";

private static String DB_NAME = "alertme";

private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;

private final Context myContext;

public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);

    this.myContext = context;
}

public void createDataBase() throws IOException {

    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

    if (dbExist) {
    } else {

        this.getReadableDatabase();

        try {
            copyDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            throw new Error("Error copying database");

        }
    }
}

private boolean checkDataBase() {

    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

    try {
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    } catch (SQLiteException e) {

    }

    if (checkDB != null) {

        checkDB.close();

    }

    return checkDB != null ? true : false;
}

private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {

    InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();

}

public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

}


@Override
public synchronized void close() {

    if (myDataBase != null)
        myDataBase.close();

    super.close();

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}
```

}

**Activity.class**

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private static DataBaseHelper mDbHelper;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);

    try {

        mDbHelper.createDataBase();

    } catch (IOException ioe) {

        throw new Error("Unable to create database");
    }

    try {
        mDbHelper.openDataBase();

    } catch (SQLException sqle) {

        throw sqle;
    }
}
```

}

**People model**

```
public class People {

private String PeopleName;
private int PeopleId;


public People(String peopleName,int peopleId) {
    this.PeopleId = peopleId;
    this.PeopleName = peopleName;
}


public String getPeopleName() {
    return PeopleName;
}

public void setPeopleName(String peopleName) {
    PeopleName = peopleName;
}

public int getPeopleId() {
    return PeopleId;
}

public void setPeopleId(int peopleId) {
    PeopleId = peopleId;
}
```

}

**Category model**

```
public class Category {
int CategoryId;
String  CategoryName;

public Category(int categoryId,String categoryName){
    this.CategoryId = categoryId;
    this.CategoryName = categoryName;
}

public int getCategoryId() {
    return CategoryId;
}

public void setCategoryId(int categoryId) {
    CategoryId = categoryId;
}

public String getCategoryName() {
    return CategoryName;
}

public void setCategoryName(String categoryName) {
    CategoryName = categoryName;
}
```

}

Comment: http://dj-android.blogspot.in/2012/10/android-show-data-from-sqlite-db-into.html  use this tutorial

Comment: But my data is already add in DB Browser for SQLITE.

Comment: what is the problem in that??

Comment: how to show this data from Listview or logcat?

Comment: I have static add data in DB Browser.

Comment: You have any idea how to do this?

Comment: @JaydeepDhamecha You have to copy your sqlite file into assets folder and then Need to apply logic on the database what ever you want.See this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6787466/how-to-import-sqlite-into-database-in-sqlite-on-android

Comment: Thanks @Anil You any example?

Comment: @JaydeepDhamecha Here is an example with good explanation http://androidgifts.com/import-sqlite-database-into-android-using-sqlite-browser/

Comment: Thanks @Anil problem sole it..

Comment: If you know ans in this qu:-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39746341/how-to-pass-position-wise-object-data-one-activity-to-another-using-recyclerview